# Requesting a Firebase Messaging Token without installing the firebase package on frontend

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have a Go backend that registers users and obtains an access token that is saved in a mongo collection

I was wondering if it was possible to not have the javascript firebase package installed/saved and instead make a call to an endpoint that Google have to return a messaging token?

We have this function:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging(); 

function initialiseFirebaseMessagingNotifications() {
  messaging
    .requestPermission()
    .then(function() {
      console.log("main.js || Notification permission granted");
      return messaging.getToken();
    })...
```

Which then saves the token in the database

**Do we need to use the firebase package here?!** I want to make a call to an endpoint, not have to install the javascript firebase package

I was guessing that in the request we'd include:

- The access token from Firebase auth
- Our server credentials (Go)

Does anyone have an example of this, or can state whether it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.  Your backend needs to collect a messaging token *from the client*, which is where the token originates.  The only way to get this token is using the Firebase SDK on that client.  You can't manufacture your own messaging tokens from a backend, nor can your backend "reach into" the client to extract the string.  It must be intentionally delivered to the backend from the client.

Firebase Authentication will not help you here at all, as messages are delivered to *devices*, not *users*.  It's up to you to map messaging device tokens to end users, if that's what you want.

In short, there is no skipping the client setup instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client).

Comment: Thanks, i'm thinking that we'll use the Firebase CDN over NPM and see what security thinks about that - they want to avoid installing external packages and SDKs